# Using a global variable in Pweave template

Tags: python, pweave

Looking at the documentation for pweave [here](http://mpastell.com/pweave/pweave.html), it appears to be possible to access any data generated inside a template by the calling program, by setting the `returnglobals` variable.

**Is it possible to do the opposite?**, i.e. have the template reference a global variable in the calling script?

My use case is that I first pull some data from an SQL database, and then call `pweave.pweave()` using that data to populate the template. Currently I'm doing this by writing an intermediate file and then loading this in a preamble in the template. I would like to instead just pass this in as part of the global scope. I've tried declaring a variable `global` in the template, but this doesn't appear to work; I keep getting exception `NameError`.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done as follows:

In the calling script :

```py
from pweave import Pweb
Pweb.globals = { "foo" : "bar" } # This creates a global var `foo` with value 'bar'
w = Pweb("inputfile.tex")        # Generate a Pweb class. We can't just call `pweave()`
w.weave()                        # Equivalent of `pweave()`
```

In the tex template:

```
The value of foo is <%=print(foo)%>
```

which will print "The value of foo is bar".

The reason for the weird dictionary is that the code uses the following call to evaluate your code:

```py
exec compiled in Pweb.globals
```

You can get more information in the [Python Documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement)